Statistics homework problem: Operating room schedule probability
Suppose that an operating room needs to schedule three knee, four hip, and five shoulder surgeries. Assume all schedules are equally likely. Determine the probability for which of the following: a. All hip surgeries are completed before another type of surgery. b. The schedule begins with a hip surgery. c. The first and the last surgeries are hip surgeries. d. The first two surgeries are hip surgeries.

What have you tried? (b) looks like the easiest.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

And (d) is the next easiest, after (b). And if you can solve (b) and (d), then you can solve (a), also pretty easyly. That leaves (c); which is trickier...

@jginestet though really (c) is not much harder than (d).
